# How to write a custom form helper template for dynamically generated content?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scala, playframework

I have some sort of quiz system, where to user gets shown a question and several answer-options with radio-buttons.

But as I am using a helper for a inputRadioGroup that gets filled via a list, it does not look pretty anymore (like Twitter Bootstrap). The radiobuttons are inline, while they should be underneath each other. And actually I would like to change the icon to a prettier button.

This is how it looks at the moment:

[image: Example]

Therefore I tried to write my own custom form helper, but keep getting stuck. I find it frustratingly hard to understand the documentation for this:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaFormHelpers

First I created a new template named **myFieldConstructorTemplate.scala.html**

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)

<div class="@if(elements.hasErrors) {error}">
<label for="@elements.id">@elements.label</label>
<div class="input">
    @elements.input
    <span class="errors">@elements.errors.mkString(", ")</span>
    <span class="help">@elements.infos.mkString(", ")</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Saved it to the /views-folder. Then try to use it in my view class **quiz.scala.html:**

```
@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._

@(questionList: List[Question], answerList: List[Answer], answerRadioForm: Form[Answer])

@helper.form(action = routes.Application.nextQuizPage(), 'id -> "answerRadioForm"){
    @helper.inputRadioGroup(
    answerRadioForm("Answer"),
    options = answerList.map(answer => answer.answerID.toString -> answer.answerText),
    '_label -> "Answer",
    '_error -> answerRadioForm("answerID").error.map(_.withMessage("select answer")))
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Send">
    Next Question
</button>
}
@implicitField = @{ FieldConstructor(myFieldConstructorTemplate.f) }
@inputText(answerRadioForm("questionID"))
```

If I put this into my template, I get a `not found: value implicitField`-error.

So how can I manage to change the appearance of my radiobuttons to underneath and looking like Twitter Bootstrap?

**[EDIT1]:** I have changed the order of the imports to the suggested version:

```
@(questionList: List[Question], answerList: List[Answer], answerRadioForm: Form[Answer])

@import helper._
@implicitField = @{ FieldConstructor(myFieldConstructorTemplate.f) }
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._
```

I get this error then:

```
ambiguous implicit values: 
both method implicitField of type => views.html.helper.FieldConstructor 
and value twitterBootstrapField in package twitterBootstrap of type 
=> views.html.helper.FieldConstructor match expected type 
views.html.helper.FieldConstructor
```

I think this has to do with the way I import the answers into the radiobuttons?

**[EDIT2]:**
The order of the imports is now:

```
@(questionList: List[Question], answerList: List[Answer], answerRadioForm: Form[Answer])

@import models.Question
@import models.Answer

@import helper._
@implicitField = @{ FieldConstructor(myFieldConstructorTemplate.f) }
```

With this, the program compiles. BUT the radiobuttons still look the same. So I tried to change the design, which does not quite work. It looks now like all the radiobuttons are melted into a single one:

[image: Monty Python]

Here is my template class **myFieldConstructorTemplate.scala.html**:

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)

<div class="btn-group", data-toggle="buttons">
<label for="@elements.id">@elements.label</label>
<div class="input">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
    @elements.input
    <span class="errors">@elements.errors.mkString(", ")</span>
    <span class="help">@elements.infos.mkString(", ")</span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
```

**[EDIT3]:** I have changed my class according [to the last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30946591/1368690), but still the radiobuttons are melted into each other. So I want to point out that I am not fixated on using the [inputRadioGroup from the playframework helper](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/views/html/helper/inputRadioGroup$.html), if there is another solution that works the same and looks almost like bootstrap, I would gladly use that. It seems that changing the helper isnt that easy / intuitive. I appreciate any form of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Twitter Bootstrap structure needs to be accurate.

Wrap the `btn-group` class around the `inputRadioGroup` helper like so:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
@helper.inputRadioGroup(
    answerRadioForm("Answer"),
    options = answerList.map(answer => answer.answerID.toString -> answer.answerText),
    '_label -> "Answer",
    '_error -> answerRadioForm("answerID").error.map(_.withMessage("select answer")))
</div>
```

Then replace the template with:

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)

<label class="btn btn-primary">
    @elements.input @elements.label
</label>

<span class="errors">@elements.errors.mkString(", ")</span>
<span class="help">@elements.infos.mkString(", ")</span>
```

In general, perhaps it'd be of interest another way of doing it.  When you use `fooForm("myField"...)`, you can use `fooForm("myField[@i]"...)` in a `for` loop where `@i` is a counter going from 0 to however many inputs there are.  Then you can yourself sketch out the full HTML instead of using implicit values.

By the way, the documentation with the Scala version about all this has lots more information than the Java version. See [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaForms). It has more information on `inputRadioGroup` than the Java version of the documentation but still very useful reading for better understanding of all this.

Some [Play Bootstrap plugin](https://github.com/adrianhurt/play-bootstrap3/blob/master/module/app/views/b3/checkbox.scala.html) has code available on GitHub that is also useful reading especially as it uses implicit values also.

#### UPDATE

Here's a couple of GitHub projects showing how to achieve this:

- with Scala version of Play: https://github.com/bjfletcher/play-bootstrap-radio-group
- with Java version of Play: https://github.com/bjfletcher/play-java-bootstrap-radio-group

Screenshot of the result:

[image]

Comment: I've edited your suggestions into my templates, but it's still not working. This is how it looks now: http://i.imgur.com/7i5f85i.jpg
I find the documentation for the custom helper extremly confusing for a beginner like me. More examples or tutorials in the docs would help. I dont know Scala, so I dont understand much of the docs there. In the github example are no comments, i.e. why is `@containsReadonly` there? What is it used for? How can I change it? Do I need to change it? ... especially the mixture of scala, html and bootstrap is hard to grasp and understand.

Comment: Hi @hamena314, just put together a project for you - see updated answer. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: There's now a Java version as well as a Scala version on GitHub. See updated answer.

Comment: Wow, this works! Thank you. :)
This is much simpler than my approach with a custom template, I even can design this some more myself. Another question: Is it possible to only work with the HTML like in this case without writing a custom helper template? Or does it have benefits to write one? I'm starting to like the play framework, but think that for a beginner certain aspects are badly documented like for the custom helper.

Comment: Oh and why is a radio-group not necessary? You seem to put together only classes of radio-buttons. I kept searching for a radioGroup, seems like my approach to searching was wrong then.

Comment: Thanks - I'm so glad we've finally unlocked the deadlock for you - welcome to the world of Play web platform! Re your question - yes you can do everything without using Play's form helpers. For example, with the GitHub projects, replace the form helper with: <form action="/path/to/post" method="post">, then it's 100% free of their helpers. In working with Bootstrap, I find it best to write our own for complicated parts because Play form helpers' HTML structures sometimes don't work well with Bootstrap's expected structures. Use either anytime. Enjoy :)

Comment: Re radio-group - I think you were thinking of button group -> http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio (you can use this instead using a similar technique as in my projects).

Answer (score 1):

Move the `implicitField`-definition to the top of the file:

```
@(questionList: List[Question], answerList: List[Answer], answerRadioForm: Form[Answer])
@import helper._
@implicitField = @{ FieldConstructor(myFieldConstructorTemplate.f) }
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._

@helper.form(action = routes.Application.nextQuizPage(), 'id -> "answerRadioForm"){
    @helper.inputRadioGroup(
    answerRadioForm("Answer"),
    options = answerList.map(answer => answer.answerID.toString -> answer.answerText),
    '_label -> "Answer",
    '_error -> answerRadioForm("answerID").error.map(_.withMessage("select answer")))
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Send">
    Next Question
</button>
}
@inputText(answerRadioForm("questionID"))
```

This makes sure the implicit value is available where it's needed.

Comment: If I do this, I get an compilation error `not found: value questionList` in the line `@(questionList: List[Question], answerList: List[Answer], answerRadioForm: Form[Answer])`.
If I move the line `@implicitField = ...` beneath the `@questionList:...` Line, I get this error: `ambiguous implicit values: both value twitterBootstrapField in package twitterBootstrap of type => views.html.helper.FieldConstructor and method implicitField of type => views.html.helper.FieldConstructor match expected type views.html.helper.FieldConstructor`

Comment: I tried your version, but keep getting errors, see my edited post.

Answer (score 1):

Always keep params on top of template and remove the following import statement `@import helper.twitterBootstrap._` this will conflict with your own field constructor.

```
@(questionList: List[Question], answerList: List[Answer], answerRadioForm: Form[Answer])

@import helper._
@implicitField = @{ FieldConstructor(myFieldConstructorTemplate.f) }
```

Hope it resolves your issue.

Comment: I tried your version as well, but I keep getting an error. Please see my edit.

Comment: Remove the following import statement @import helper.twitterBootstrap._  and try .

Comment: Removed the import statement, now my program compiles. But it looks exactly the same as in the picture I have posted. The radiobuttons are still inline, the text is still bold and it does not look like bootstrap.

Comment: @hamena314 What you are seeing is the default behaviour, in order to make it your way, you need to include respective bootstrap css selectors.

Comment: @hamena314 Have a look at this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio) for setting radio buttons in twitter bootstrap.

Comment: I appreciate your effort in helping me. Sadly, my program still does not work like it is intended. I have edited my post (see edit2). Any ideas?